# Single GKScene with a BaseGame class being shared with multiple subclasses

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skscene

I have a SpriteKit scene file, 1 SKScene `BaseGameClass` which contains all the common logic for my game and 2 `BaseGameClass` subclasses for different game modes.

Both subclasses are basically the same game play but with different rules / end game state, etc.

In my Main Menu scene, I do this:

```
switch node.name ?? "" {
    case "lblQuickGame":
        if let scene = GKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Get the SKScene from the loaded GKScene
            if let sceneNode = scene.rootNode as! QuickGameScene? {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                sceneNode.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                sceneNode.initializeGame(
                    gameSeed: .random(),
                    level: 1
                )
                self.view?.presentScene(sceneNode, transition: MenuScene.customSceneTransition())
            }
        }
...
...
```

The problem I have is that the game crashes with this error

```
Could not cast value of type 'SKScene' (0x107e0a1e0) to 'xxxx.QuickGameScene'
```

This is complaining about where I cast the `scene.rootNode`.

Is it possible to have a single SKS file but allow it to be loaded with different subclasses for the root node?!

---

Update:

[image: SKS setting]

This is how my SKS file is setup. I'd like to avoid having 1 SKS per BaseGameScene subclass as they're all going to be identical and it'd going to become a PITA to maintain ;)

---

I wonder if my issue is about inheritance (in this case I'm trying to case a superclass to a subclass, which you cant really do in OO) vs some kind of abstract interface?

Comment: you are forcing the cast in this line `if let sceneNode = scene.rootNode as! QuickGameScene?`you need to use `if let sceneNode = scene.rootNode as? QuickGameScene`

Comment: a question, are you sure that your "GameScene" have a rootNode of type `QuickGameScene`?

Comment: I've tried my GameScene on SKScene and BaseGameScene - same error... I'll try switching out `!` for `?`...

Comment: You need to make sure the custom class in your SKS file is set to "QuickGameScene"

Comment: @ReinierMelian - switching `!` and `?` has stopped the error, but now the `if` doesn't resolve ;) So the Menu no longer works.

@Knight0fDragon I dont want to make the SKS specific to that type - The point of this question is that I have 1 SKS that uses the BaseGameClass and I have subclasses of that to control it depending on the game type. I dont want to have to clone the SKS file for each game type.

Comment: @Nick you need to make your root node class == to one of your `BaseGameClass` subclasses

Comment: @ReinierMelian yes.. so that fixes my problem for one of the game modes. But then I cant load the other... For example, I have a TimeTrailGameClass and a QuickGameClass subclass from BaseGameClass. I want both subclasses to be able to use the same SKS scene file. I know I can half-solve the problem by setting the SKS file to use a subclass, but that sort of "moves the problem", it doesn't solve it ;)

Comment: Your game nodes must be only of one type, TimeTrailGameClass or QuickGameClass

Comment: @ReinierMelian so you're saying a single SKS file cannot change its rootNode programmatically?

Comment: I've found this: `if let scene = GKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene", rootNode: TimeTrailGameScene()) {` - but during the `sceneDidLoad` in the BaseGameClass, it can no longer find any children on the scene ;)

Comment: I don't know if a SKS file can have 2 rootNodes but if can must be an array and one must be of one subclass and the other rootNode another subclass @Nick

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out! The MainMenu scene doesn't need to do GKScene stuff, it can just load the GameScene file using the appropriate class directly and present that scene. Also, I had to remove any Custom Class value from my SKS file.

```
func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    let node = self.atPoint(pos)

    guard let view = self.view else {
        NSLog("No View Found")
        return
    }

    switch node.name ?? "" {
    case "lblTimeTrail":
        guard let scene = TimeTrailGameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") else {
            NSLog("GameScene not Found")
            return
        }
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        scene.initializeGame(
            gameSeed: .random(),
            level: 1
        )

        view.presentScene(scene, transition: MenuScene.customSceneTransition())

    case "lblQuickGame":
        guard let scene = QuickGameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") else {
            NSLog("GameScene not Found")
            return
        }
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        scene.initializeGame(
            gameSeed: .init(a: .cow, b: .snake, c: .goose),
            level: 1
        )

        view.presentScene(scene, transition: MenuScene.customSceneTransition())

    default:
            NSLog("Unknown node: %@", node)
    }
}
```

NOTE: I can probably make this code far more elegant. Make it work, then make it faster/better ;)

The `GKScene(fileNamed: ..., rootNode: ...)` route was a dead end. That's a completely undocumented method.

It's at moments like this I miss using an open source framework like Cocos2D... At least then I could dig into the code and understand how something worked; with SpriteKit we just get the method heads and we're often just left to guess how it works!

Comment: This is not an answer, your problem has nothing to do with `GKScene`, your problem is you are casting your class to something that it isn't. (Basically you are calling a cat a lion, even though they both share the same ancestor, you cant call a cat a lion)  If you have 2 scenes that behave differently, then you really should have 2 different SKS files, and use an `SKReferenceNode` to `GameScene` to link similarities between the two.  Otherwise you are defeating the purpose of separating out design.

Comment: So you'd suggest 3 SKS files, 1 GameScene and 1 for each subclass which references the GameScene?